# Circles of different size with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry

Here is the kind of data I have

```
V1 = c('a','b','a','b','c','c','c','b','b','a','c','c','c','b','a','a')
V2 = c('A','A','A','B','B','C','A','B','C','C','B','B','B','C','A','B')
```

I'd like to make a ggplot with `V1` in x-axis and `V2` in y-axis. The plot should be made of filled circles which size indicates the number of interactions. For example: in x-axis == 'a', y-axis = 'B' the circle should be of a size which depends on the number of times in `V1`and `V2` when, at the same position, there is a `a` in `V1` and a `B` in `V2`. Does it make sense?

The same kind of information could as well be displayed on a bar graph… But I'd like to try this circle representation! Below is the bar graph.

[image]

And here is my code to implement this bar graph

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(factor(Fish_sp), fill=General.substrate)) + geom_bar(stats='bin', position=position_dodge()) + coord_flip() + xlab('Fish species')
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried? Thanks.

Comment: @Henrik I haven't tried anything up to now. I don't know how to achieve this. Do you want my real data and the bar graph I get?

Comment: If you are lucky someone is willing to write all your code from scratch. But if you read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you will find that you should "show your work!", and "Questions asking for code must include attempted solutions, why they didn't work". Thus, you are much more likely to receive an answer if you show that you have put some effort in solving the problem yourself. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. You need to map size to the number of occurrences, the easiest way for me to get that data is with `dcast()` from `reshape2` followed `melt()`. Then the plotting is trivial:

```
library(reshape2)
dat <- data.frame(V1, V2)
dat.c <- dcast(dat, V1 ~ V2)
dat.m <- melt(dat.c, id.var = "V1")
ggplot(dat.m, aes(V1, variable)) + geom_point(aes(size = value))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot! I did not know we could simply do `size=value`